# Third party lib to create jar files?

Tags: java, jar

I've Goog'd but I can't find any third party library that will let you create a jar file programmatically. I amazed that even Apache commons-io doesn't seem to have such functionality.

I'd rather not implement it myself as the API is rather low level. Are there any 3rd party libraries out there that will do the job?

Edit: I meant programmatically in Java. I don't want to drop out to the shell and I don't want to work with java.io.*.

Comment: What precisely do you want to do?

Comment: I've solved what I need to do. Namely create a jar within a custom task in SBT. I did this using FileUtilities.jar(...). However my question stands. Specifically, I'm amazed that a library like apache commons-io  doesn't have a method like createJar(File target, List<File> entries, boolean recurse, Manifest manifest), for example. Because this is a community resource I'd like to find an answer for others that come after me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "creating a jar file" but ant has a [jar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) which will create a jar file for you

Comment: +1. You can also use Ant tasks programmatically by embedding them in your program (don't have to call out to an external process).

Answer (score 2):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a third party library. It's all built into Java (the jar command just uses those classes)

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html

Edit:

It will require you to still work with java.io.* as that is the only way to create files...

Comment: "You don't need a third party library. It's all built into Java". The same argument could be made for Spring, Hibernate or any other 3rd party lib.

Comment: @Synesso: The OP appears to be unaware of the existence of java.util.zip.

Comment: I think the OP talks about java.util.zip when he says "the API is rather low level."

Comment: @Thilo I'm asking for a util that wraps the 20 or 30 lines of code needed for a robust implementation of jar file creation. I could implemented it myself using Java, but I don't want to. That is just like saying I want to use Spring AOP rather than build an AOP library myself. Exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you look at [JBOSS Arquillian](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Arquillian). It provides a fluent interface to create jar, war, ear etc. See sample below

```
Archives.create("test.jar", JavaArchive.class)
               .addClasses(
                     GreetingManager.class,
                     GreetingManagerBean.class);
```